# ASP.NET Routing

Tags: asp.net, url, routes

I have sucesfully implemented url routing in my web app, the one task is not complete.

I would like to route all request from

http://www.mydomain.com/?curl=http://www.google.com

to

http://www.mydomain.com/convert.aspx?curl=http://www.google.com

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you not just get the query string from url and then do a redirect?

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to handle the `curl` parameter in your `Default.aspx` page.